# Feynman Diagrams: Fermionic Line orthogonal to Time Axis

Tags: particle-physics, feynman-diagrams

Can someone explain the meaning of this fermionic segment that is orthogonal to the time axis?

I am relatively new to Feynman diagrams and have so far only observed lines orthogonal to the time axis that correspond to exchange particles. What sort of interaction does this fermionic middle line between the vertices describe?

[image]

Comment: Vertices describe interactions. Lines describe propagators.

Answer (score 2):

In the center of mass frame with lepton momentum $k=k_z $, and final state photons with momentum $\vec k$:

$$ k_{\mu}^{e^-} = (E,0,0,k)$$
$$ k_{\mu}^{e^+} = (E,0,0,-k)$$

going to:

$$ p_{\mu}^1 = (p, p\sin{\theta}, 0, p\cos{\theta}) $$
$$ p_{\mu}^1 = (p, -p\sin{\theta}, 0, -p\cos{\theta}) $$

then:

$$ q_{\mu}=p_{\mu}^1-k_{\mu}^{e^-}=(p-E, p\sin\theta, 0, p\cos{\theta}-k)$$

describes the $t$-channel electron line.

For simplicity at first, look at back scattering, $\cos\theta =-1$, with $E\approx ||\vec k||=||\vec p||>>m_e$:

$$ q_{\mu}=(0, 0, 0, -2k)$$

which is a virtual electron carrying a lot of momentum, and very little energy.

Answer (score 0):

That internal line doesn’t describe any interaction. It describes the electron or the positron in a way that it can be either. The diagram can be interpreted in two ways: 1. The electron radiates a photon, and then annihilates with the positron. 2. The positron radiates a photon, and then annihilates with the electron.